# Center-align a div vertically

Tags: html, css, centering

I would like to vertically center align my div with the class "centeredContent". I am within a Kendo Mobile tabstrip. Maybe this is why nothing seems to be working. There may be some specific things I need to do. I have tried one specific solution that actually worked, the image was centered, but the unordered list below it actually went far to the right-hand side of the page...if we can make the unordered list not do that then that would be ace. Here is what made the image centered:

```
#outer {
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
        }
```

And having the data-stretch="true" attribute of the whole tab view.

Here is my code as it is now. I cannot post an image until I have 10 reputation but basically the centredContent div appears to be about 20px from the top, still way too high to be in the center:

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="Log In" data-layout="main" data-model="APP.models.home" data-show="showLogin">
    <h1 data-bind="html: title"></h1>
    <div class="centeredContent">
        <div>
        <img class="logo1"/><br/>
        <ul class="listView" data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
            <li>
                <label class="question">Username
                    <input type="text" value="" id="Username" />
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="question">Password
                    <input type="password" value="" id="Password" />
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <button onclick="signIn()" type="button">Submit</button>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="modalview" id="modalviewError" style="width: 90%;">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
            <li>
                <label type="text" value="" id="errMessage"></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button onclick="hidePopup()" type="button">OK</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>




</div>
```

css:

```
.centeredContent {

        position:absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        top:50%;
    }

    .logo1 {
        background-image: url(../styles/images/VCareInternationalLimited.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width:254px;
        height:129px;
        text-align: center;
        display:block;
        left:0;
        background-size: 254px 129px;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius:10px;
    }

.listView {
    width:254px;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-left :auto;
    margin-right :auto;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this site. Hope it helps. http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

Comment: @captainrad Thanks. Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `#outer` and `.centeredContent`, an effective way to do this is to use the following code:

```
#outer {
    display: table;
}
.centeredContent {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block /* Add this for IE support */
}
```

You may have to fiddle with position (try relative and absolute) if this doesn't work. You could also have a look at some other options at http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/.